# Determine if all members of a list are unique

Tags: vb.net

I searched and found several answers on how to find and/or remove duplicates from a list.  I would have been able to adapt any of these to my specific need, which is to simply find out if a list of integers has more than a single unique value.

However, it appears there is a problem with my project.  The answers I found all suggest using `Distinct()` or `GroupBy()`, which are all extension methods added in .NET 3.0.  I have verified that the project's target framework is set to 4.5, and all of the System references in the project are 4.0.30319.  When I try

```
Dim lstDupes As List(Of Integer) = lstSections.Distinct().ToList()
```

I get the error

```
'Distinct' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)'
```

The same goes for GroupBy, Select, etc.  Why can I not use these methods?

Comment: Do you have the LINQ library included in your class?

Comment: Well.  I feel stupid.  Working now though, and that's what counts.

Comment: Haha, it's okay. I did the same thing earlier.

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, LINQ Requires that you include the library. Don't forget it.

For the future peeps, you do so by typing this:

```
  Imports System.Linq
```

It happens to the best of us. :D